# How do I display a Value from an input field in a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to create a Modal Confirmation dialog that displays the text entered into a text box for them to review before submitting.

I have it all 'working' except for displaying the Text in the Modal. Below is my View. Notice the `@Model.UserName` field.  That shows nothing even though, if I click Submit on that page, it has a value once it get's back to the Controller.

So, how do I display the value of that Property or the Text box that contains it?

```
@model HelpDeskSupportRequestor.Models.SupportRequest

<h2>IT Support Request</h2>    

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestDetails, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestDetails, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestDetails, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestPriority, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestPriority)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestPriority, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Submit Request" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm IT Support Request</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>@Model.UserName</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the top of the page and confirm that Model.UserName actually has a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're expecting the typed in username to exist in the model (and hence the modal in the view).

Try using javascript to do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#UserName').on('input', function () {
  var username = $("#UserName").val();
  $(".modal-body").html('<p>'+username+'</p>');
 });
</script>
```

EDIT

In response to your comment, as you're using bootstrap and editting multiple fields,
 may as well do:

```
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var username = $("#UserName").val(); 
    var email = $("#EmailAddress").val(); 
    var priority = $("#RequestPriority").val(); 
    var request = $("#RequestDetails").val(); 
    $(".modal-body").html('<p>User Name: '+username+'</p>' +
        '<p>Email Address: '+email+'</p>' +
        '<p>Requested Priority: '+priority+'</p>' +
        '<p>Request Details: '+request+'</p>');     }); 
})
```

Comment: I am trying to accomplish that.  However, this doesn't seem to work either though I suspect it might be do to something I'm doing wrong with JavaScript.  I get an `$ Undefined` exception on startup.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin, place this at the bottom of your view. View the source of the html and make sure there is a text box with id="UserName", also breakpoint this with firebug if needed. Im presuming you're including jquery too

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add it INSIDE of the `@section Scripts{}` portion to make it work, awesome.

Comment: Kind of a follow up: why wouldn't this work for all 4 fields?
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#UserName').on('input', function () {
        var username = $("#UserName").val();
        var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();
        var priority = $("#RequestPriority").val().toString();
        var request = $("#RequestDetails").val();

        $(".modal-body").html('<p>User Name: '+username+'</p>' +
                '<p>Email Address: '+email+'</p>' +
                '<p>Requested Priority: '+priority+'</p>' +
                '<p>Request Details: '+request+'</p>');
    });
</script>`

Comment: thanks, that did it.  I see what I was overlooking in my ignorance.  I was "hooked" to the UserName control specifically and your Edit has it "hooked" to the modal shown event.  Yes?